# variable scope - how to decide

Tags: c#

If I have class "A" that I want to declare an instance of, that I use frequently within class "B", what is the deciding factor on whether I should declare it outside of class "B" or within each method I use it in within class "B"?

```
public Class A
{
}

A declareClassA = new A();
public Class B 
{
}
```

or

```
public Class B 
{
  public void MethodA()
  {
      A declareClassA = new A();
      ...
  }
  public void MethodB()
  {
      A declareClassA = new A();
      ...
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to use a new instance for each method? If so, declare and instantiate inside the method.

If not, declare it inside the class.

```
public Class B
{
    A myA = new A();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you can't (AFAIK) declare a variable outside a class.

For your first example, I think you mean:

```
public Class B 
{
   A declareClassA = new A();
   // methods here..
}
```

As for your question - do you need to use the same instance in both MethodA and MethodB, or not?

If you do, use the above code. If not, use a separate declaration in each method.

Answer (score 1):

Best practices would be to scope a variable at its lowest necessary level. If you need to share a variable between methods, then it's scope should be outside of that. If the methods operate independently and can survive with a scope at that level, then you should declare/instantiate your new variable there.

Always keep your scope as minimal as possible without reducing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In your first method, seems like A could either be a singleton pattern or a static class. This really depends on the data inside A, and if it should be reused and how many instances should exist.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you need persistent storage of that object. If you need to reference the same instance declare it as a class level variable otherwise declare it in the methods so that you can decrease coupling between your methods.

Additionally if those functions are always using Class A think about whether they should belong to Class A instead of Class B